# Snape's Pensive memory chronology question

Tags: harry-potter, chronology

Ok in the movie *Harry Potter and The Deathly Hallows: Part Two*, Harry sees a series of memories from Snape, in which you see Snape casting the Patronus for Harry to follow and thus Harry finds the Sword (which happened in *Part 1*).

When Snape casts said Patronus he is in Prof. Dumbledore's office talking with Prof. Dumbledore, but Dumbledore dies in *The Half-Blood Prince* (which is an earlier movie).

Am I missing something or have I made an incorrect conclusion?

Comment: I think you're missing the fact that the memory is from before Snape was killed. I'm not sure how this is at all unclear.

Comment: He is talking to Dumbledore when he casts the patronus!

Comment: @phantom42 I don't think the issue is when the memory was *viewed*, but rather *created*. I think OP is onto something here. Snape casts a Patronus in Prof. D's office (which is supposedly the one which leads Harry to the Sword), in the movie. But in the books Snape casts the Patronus to show Prof. D that it is in fact a "Doe" Patronus which happens to prove his love for Lily (since hers was the same). Whereas the Patronus leading Harry to the Sword happened in *DH:P1*! In the books, Snape casts two separate Patroni, IIRC.

Comment: Dumbledore is long dead at this point

Comment: IIRC, the conversation also touches upon the fact that Snape is to kill Dumbledore instead of Draco. Clearly, the conversation happened either during or before HBP. I still don't understand how this is unclear.

Comment: 1. Snape kills Dumbledoor in the sixth movie

Comment: 2. Harry follows a Doe patronus in the seventh movie

Comment: 3. Harry learns that said patronus was cast by Snape .  (The vision clearly shows Dumbledore AND Snape together).

Comment: BUT Dumbledore dies in six.  How can he be present when Snape casts the pronus in seven

Comment: Maybe the confusion is about number. Those were two _different_ Patronii, cast at _different_ times.

Answer (score 10):

I think I understand the question so I will provide an answer.

Chronological order of the events that interest you:

1. Snape casts a Patronus in Dumbledore's office. Because Dumbledore is alive, we assume it's sometime during the *Half-Blood Prince* (6th book/movie). This is just to show that his Patronus mirrors his feelings for Lily.
2. Dumbledore dies at the end of the *Half-Blood Prince* (6th book/movie).
3. Snape then, much much later, during the *Deathly Hallows* casts a NEW patronus that leads Harry to Sword of Gryffindor.

**I belive you though it was one Patronus the whole time, but he just cast it multiple times.**

Comment: @michael if that is the answer you were looking for, you should accept it (and probably up-vote it): this is explained in the [help](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).